# Maximal ideal and Prime ideal

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals

Does anyone know how did the idea of maximal and prime ideal came into existence for the first time ? I want to understand their applicability in mathematics.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805778/maximal-ideal-prime-ideal

Comment: "First time" oh boy...

Comment: In $\mathbb Z$ the only prime ideals are the sets $p\mathbb Z$ of multiples of  $p$ where $p$ is prime . These sets are also the only maximal ideals. They have as important property that there are not zero divisors what means that $ab=0\Rightarrow$ $a=0$ or $b=0$. For example in $6\mathbb Z$ you have $2\cdot 3=0$ which is possible because $6$ is not prime.